# Select multiple table rows with php

Tags: php

Hi I have a table populated from MYSQL, what i am trying to do is have a check box on each row where i can just select and then press one button and update all of the selected rows with one press.

Here is the code for my checkboxes.

```
 <input type='checkbox' name='checked[]' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>
```

And here is my PHP Code

```
 if ($_POST['submit']){ //check if they submitted

  //see which check boxes were selected
  foreach ($_POST['checked'] as $key => $val){

  //update records
  $result = mysql_query("UPDATE masterip_details SET type='3' WHERE id='$key'") 
             or die(mysql_error()); 
    }
  }
```

At the moment nothing happens, and if i try and echo key then i get no id's

Comment: Try basic debugging.. Check what you have in $_POST['checked']; and also in $row['id'].

Comment: @user1691024 You have to pass `id='$val'` instead of `$key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$val` instead of $key. `$key` will only contain the index of the order of `checked[]`

I have also removed the `if($_POST['submit'])` code and replaced it with `if(count($_POST['checked']>0))`

```
if (count($_POST['checked']>0)){
    foreach ($_POST['checked'] as $key => $val){

        $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);

        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE masterip_details SET type='3' WHERE id='{$val}'");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but when i tried to add your code to dreamweaver it showed there was an error around the line if

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, I missed out a character. I have edited the code now, so it should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox that isn't checked won't be send to the server, and I remember something about it only sending 1 if it is checked.

So, you can change your script to:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checked[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]' />
```

And check it with the $key